# How To Use Variable Found With Macro Within Macro

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I have a subroutine finding the address of a cell containing a specific string. I am capturing the address of this cell as a variable `x` and then I want to select that cell. What I have thus far is:

```
Call FindCell("n")
Sheets("Lagrange").Range(X).Select
```

The variable `X` is what the `FindCell` subroutine is returning as `"$D$2"`

Comment: ```X = FindCell("n")```

Comment: `FindCell` should really return a `Range`, not a `String`.

Comment: No need for X: `Sheets("Lagrange").Range(FindCell("n")).Select`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 that won't work because he's using a Sub, not a function. I think that's where the disconnect is....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're being tripped up by using a `SUB` to set a variable value. A `Function` is the proper method to your issue.

```
Sub yourMacro()
Const someText = "something to find"

findMyCell(someText).Select   

End Sub


Private Function findMyCell(textToFind As String) As Range


    Set findMyCell = ws.UsedRange.Find(textToFind, LookIn:=xlFormulas)


End Function
```

Here's an example with a variable:

```
Sub yourMacrowithVariable()
Const someText = "something to find"

Dim aRange As Range
    Set aRange = findMyCell(someText)

aRange.Select
'or Range(aRange.Address).Select


End Sub
```